# Spacy download on Apple M1 chip

Tags: docker, spacy, apple-m1

I'm in a MacBook Pro with M1 Pro chip, and I've built a Docker to install Tensorflow, spacy, etc.
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install TensorFlow==2.3.4
RUN pip install rasa==2.8.0
RUN pip install spacy 
RUN python -m spacy download pt_core_news_lg
```

I've added platform tag (linux/x86_64) in line 1, to install correctly the TensorFlow and spacy packages. But, when run the spacy download command, occurs this error.

```
 => ERROR [13/13] RUN python -m spacy download pt_core_news_lg                                                                                                                                  2.3s
------
 > [13/13] RUN python -m spacy download pt_core_news_lg:
#17 2.290 2022-01-10 19:36:31.774553: F tensorflow/core/lib/monitoring/sampler.cc:42] Check failed: bucket_limits_[i] > bucket_limits_[i - 1] (0 vs. 10)
#17 2.290 qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
#17 2.300 Aborted
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c python -m spacy download pt_core_news_lg]: exit code: 134
```

Any idea?

Comment: spaCy doesn't use TensorFlow so no idea what's going on with that. Failures due to signals without much info are often due to architecture mismatches. Maybe ask in the spaCy installation board and provide the output of `spacy info`. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions

Comment: In this project, I'm using rasa technology. So, Tensorflow and Spacy are necessaries to use rasa correctly. I've runned spacy download to download Portuguese language package to use in rasa. In another laptop, with Intel, the dockerfile run correctly.

Comment: `qemu: uncaught target signal 6` means that the x86_64 emulation that allows running intel docker images on apple arm64 has failed in some way. I don't know if there's a work around, but I think some images are just unable to run emulated